# Add More Columns to Color Palette in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, colors, presentations, color-profiles

Can you add more color columns to the color palette (for font/highlight colors) in PowerPoint?

I like the existing color palette, but it would be great, if I can pick more colors for my presentations. I would like to add Columns with more color shades.

With most computers/laptops having larger screens/resolutions, I think, it can be useful to have more color choices.

[image]

Any ideas?

**Note:** I am using Office 2016.

Comment: This palette is built into PPT itself and isn't modifiable. If you're good with VBA or some other coding languages, you could probably create your own color gallery and the code to apply colors to selected shapes/text/etc. But it'd be quite an undertaking ...

Comment: Yes, it seems pretty challenging. Thanks though.